# How to find largest value from array of NSDictionary objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

How to find largest value from `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`?

Here is my code,

```
NSDictionary *d1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:35] forKey:@"data"];
NSDictionary *d2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:52] forKey:@"data"];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:d1, d2, nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.data == %@.@max.data", array];
```

However this sometimes gives wrong results. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way for NSNumber values

```
NSNumber *max = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.data"];
```

and

```
NSNumber *max = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.data.floatValue"];
```

for NSString/NSNumbers mixed values.

Comment: Its work fine, but fail in case of string value like:    NSDictionary *d1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"35.9" forKey:@"data"];
NSDictionary *d2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"52.12" forKey:@"data"];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:d1, d2, nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.data == %@.@max.data", array];

Comment: @SachinKumaram It is only for numbers. Please use this notation
NSDictionary *d1 = @{@"data":@(35.9)}; 
NSDictionary *d2 = @{@"data":@(52.12)};
NSArray *array = @[d1,d2];
Now it should work

Comment: I can't change the nsdictionary, because it coming from API.Like:  (
                        {
                data = 0;
                time = "2014-03-10";
            },
            {
                data = "192.3";
                time = "2014-03-12";
            },
            {
                data = "858.3";
                time = "2014-03-14";
            })